# Words into a binary heap

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap

Show the formation of a min binary heap with the following words. They are inserted in the following order: There, will, be, Consequences, jim.

I know that the words with capital letters are considered to be smaller than the other words starting with non-capital letters. If there is only one word with a capital letter then, i know that we can represent it on top. However, how do we show a heap where there are two words with capital letters.

And why does capital letters are considered to be smaller than non-capital letters?

Thank you

Comment: [What kind of heap?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Variants)

Comment: You look absolutely lost. Why are you trying to do this? Is it homework? What do you want from us? What did you try before asking?

Comment: @user270349 I am not lost. And i have stated what i know, meaning i have tried drawing the actual heap. But when it comes to the capital lettered words, i get confused, as in binary tree, when you are forming a binary tree with words, capital lettered words appear on the top, thus, i was wondering whether its similar to that. And the given example is not my homework, the example was self-created.

Comment: Use String.compareTo to compare, it will consider capitals are before non-capital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's consider how the words are to be sorted:

`Consequences < There < be < jim  < will`

so we can give them numbers so it's easier to work with:

```
1 = Consequences
2 = There
3 = be
4 = jim
5 = will
```

First we add `There == 2`:

```
                                       2
```

then `will == 5` and `be == 3`:

```
                                       2
                                      / \
                                     5   3
```

so far so good. But now when adding `Consequences == 1` we have to heapify:

```
                          2                 1
                        /   \              / \
                       5     3     ==>    2   3
                      /                  /
                     1                  5
```

And finally we add `jim == 4`:

```
                                         1
                                        / \
                                       2   3
                                      / \
                                     5   4
```

As to comparing letters, it's because ASCII coding. So the letters go as follows:

`A < B < C < .. < Z < a < b < c < ... < z`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean building the heap iteratively and heapifying after each insertion if needed. We simply need to start adding the words:

First, you simply add There:

```
  There
```

Then, you add 'will'

```
      There
will
```

Similarly for 'be'

```
      There
will        be
```

Now, you add Consequences:

```
                   There
            will         be
Consequences
```

But `Consequences < will` so you need to sift up:

```
                     There
       Consequences         be
will
```

And again, because `Consequences < There`

```
                Consequences  
       There                  be
will
```

Now, we can add 'jim':

```
                Consequences  
       There                  be
will        jim
```

And since `There<jim` - we are done!

Comment: Ah...so the capital letters are compared with one another. Meaning Z > A. So its like forming binary search tree with words

Comment: @Phantom Not exactly, because this is not a binary search tree - this is a heap. Note that `Consequences < There`, and yet - 'There' is the left subtree of 'Consequences'. This behavior is not correct for a binary search tree.

Comment: Yup, i am seeing the difference now. Got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Capital letters are lexicographically smaller when referring to the ASCII-Table (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange), perhaps you meant that.

Comment: This only answers a very small part of the question, the main question is about formation of the min heap formed from these words.

Answer (score 0):

**You'd build a min-heap the way you would with numbers, but instead of numerical comparison, you'll be doing lexicographic comparisons**.

Comparing 2 words lexicographically/alphabetically works like this: compare the first letter, if equal, compare the next one, etc.

**Capital letters are considered "smaller" because they have a lower character code value. That is, they are lexicographically smaller, because they come "before" the small-case letters**. If you look at an ASCII table:

[image]

You see that `A` has the ASCII value of 65, whereas `a` has the value of 97. Unicode has the same character codes for these letters, so the same is true there.

Comment: This only answers a very small part of the question, the main question is about formation of the min heap formed from these words.